# SSIS 2005: Buffer swap even when enough RAM available

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I run (debug) a SSIS package in Visual Studio 2005.
When it's in the middle of doing a complex data flow task, I can see TMP files appearing in a folder that I specified against the **BufferTempStoragePath** data flow property, as per: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/01/set-blobtempstoragepath-and-buffertempstoragepath-to-fast-drives.aspx

When these files are being output, I can see in Windows Task Manager --> Performance that RAM usage goes up a bit, but there still seems to be enough RAM available so why is SSIS swapping data to disk?

[image: SSIS running and TMP files being output]

As far as I understand from the link above:

***Now what could cause a buffer to swap? There are two possible causes. The first one is when a memory allocation fails. The second one is when Windows signals the low memory resource notification event. Both will trigger SSIS to reduce its working set. SSIS does so by moving buffer data to disk.***

How do I check which condition (i.e. memory allocation failure or low memory resource notification) is the cause in my case? I enabled SSIS logging and I output OnError, OnWarning and OnInformation package events to a database table, and I also output BufferSizeTuning and PipelineInitialization events from the data flow in question, but I cannot see any outputs relating to  memory allocation failure or low memory resource notification?

The following Microsoft articles mention monitoring the **Buffers spooled** performance counter (under **SQL Server:SSISPipeline**) in the Performance Monitor, but I use Windows 7 on my Dev machine and I can only see SQL Server: SSIS Pipeline 11.0 and 12.0 (which are 2012 and 2014 versions) as these are the only full SSIS instances running on my machine, so I am not sure how I can monitor Buffers Spooled when debugging a SSIS 2005 package?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms141031.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137622(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Run the package outside of the debugger (Shift-F5) Do you still get memory pressure? My assumption is that it will be no

Comment: I do not seem to be able to run it without debugging on my machine - the command prompt seem to run the validation for a few seconds and then error message is printed: "SSIS Error Cpde DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW. The Product Level is insufficient for component Merge Join. - I think this is because I do not have SQL Server 2005 installed on my machine, only Visual Studio and Management Studio 2005, which I think means that only the debugger is installed.

Comment: That does present a predicament. The debugger is a 32 bit app so it's constrained at a maximum of 4GB of addressable memory but realistically it's going to be more like 3-2 GB. That's for the Debugger *and* the enclosed exe, DTEXEC to play in. Running the package outside of the debugger (shift-F5 or from the commandline) removes that artificial memory restriction as well as improves performance. However, for that to work, the Integration Services Service must be installed from the SQL Server 2005 installation media. Otherwise, you fail a licensing check and can only execute from within BIDS

Comment: Either post pictures of your Data Flow or look at Jorg's article [SSIS – Non-blocking, Semi-blocking and Fully-blocking components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx) How many partially and fully blocking components are on your data flows? How many Lookups with Full cache option against whole tables do you have? That's likely where your memory is getting eaten up. Also, make sure you're fully patched up [SQL Server 2005 SP4, CU3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2507769) locally and on the server